# Camera Calibration using one Circle

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, camera-calibration

I am looking for implementing Camera Calibration using OpenCV python. Instead of chessboard as the target object, I would like to use one Single Circle on a board with fixed radius.

Is there any implementation on this? It would be great if someone share any repositories. Can I use OpenCV's built-in calibration function?

Thanks in advance!

Jubair

Comment: do you think a single circle is sufficient? how is that supposed to work?

Comment: What do you want to estimate? Lens distortion? Focal length? Principal point? Extrinsics?

Comment: Now that for any conic there is a family with three real degrees of freedom of projective transformations that leave that conic fixed. So calibrating using a circle will not be able to account for these. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654276/35416 for some related discussion.

Comment: @Micka:  All of those, intrinsic and extrinsic.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz: I have a vague understanding of this currently. I am just motivated by the idea that, if we multiply a circle with camera matrices, then we might end up having an ellipse.

Comment: @MvG : Oh! Thanks...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.